# How to get comments on Reviews using FQL Facebook

Tags: c#, c, facebook

How can i get the comments posted in reviews using FQL.

http://www.facebook.com/#!/CasaMadronaHotel?sk=reviews

i want the comment
"WOW - I would be nervous staying here after such problems you have experienced. "

Comment: I got the reviews using the following fql                       SELECT review_id, message, rating from review where reviewee_id=111426241260.   Now i want the comments posted on this review that is "Lucky enough to find sitters? R U Kiddin' ME? You are the luckiest mom in the world when it comes to sitters! Mam-Maw and Pap-Paw's Babysitting! 30 years of experience! LOL!" from Kim Sumpter Maggard.

Comment: Why fql query "SELECT review_id, message, rating from review where reviewee_id=323684761053987" return empty object?

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you are talking about, look at this URL

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/Review/

Should help you in reading review comments of apps or pages